# Calling a trait's superclass method from an unrelated object

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection, traits

At present we have dozens of traits that contain the following method:

```
trait ThisTrait extends SuperTrait {
  override def getList: List[String] = 
    List(/* invariant list of strings */) ::: super.getList
}
```

where "invariant" means that each instance of `MyTrait` has the same base list, likewise each instance of `SuperTrait` has the same base list, etc.  It's wasteful to recompute this every time the method is called, and so I'd like to change all of these to something like the following

```
trait ThisTrait extends SuperTrait {
  override def getList: List[String] = GetList.getList(super.getList)
}

// see edit below for a modified version of htis
private object GetList {
  private val baseList = (/* invariant list of strings */)
  private var thisList = null
  def getList(superList: List[String]) = {
    if(thisList == null) thisList = baseList ::: superList
    thisList
  }
}
```

which isn't *too* awful since `super.getList` will also be returning a (mostly) precomputed list, however I'd prefer if I could do something like the following

```
private object GetList {
  private val thisList = (/* invariant list of strings */) ::: MyTrait.super.getList
  def getList = thisList
}
```

I could do something like this via `MyTrait.getClass.getSuperclass.getMethod("getList")`, but I was hoping that there was a type-safe way of doing this (besides hard-coding a reference to `SuperTrait`'s `GetList` object)

Edit: I could improve this via

```
private object GetList {
  private val baseList = (/* invariant list of strings */)
  private var thisList = null
  def getList(superList: => List[String]) = {
    if(thisList == null) thisList = baseList ::: superList
    thisList
  }
}
```

so I won't call `super.getList` unless it's needed, however I'm still interested in knowing if there's a type-safe way of doing something like `MyTrait.super.getList`

Answer (score 1):

No, and it's a good thing. If it was possible, you could break class invariants in many cases. I am also pretty sure that if you call the method via reflection, you'll get the same implementation as calling `MyTrait`'s `getList`, and an infinite loop.